# Not able to set from clause with subquery in Hibernate 6

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-6.x

I have the below piece of the code to get count query form the original query.

But this is the line causing the issue at compile time.
`countQuery.from(sqmSubQuery);`

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
SqmSubQuery sqmSubQuery = (SqmSubQuery<Tuple>) countQuery.subquery(Tuple.class);
SqmSelectStatement sqmOriginalQuery = (SqmSelectStatement) query;
SqmQuerySpec sqmOriginalQuerySpec = sqmOriginalQuery.getQuerySpec();
sqmSubQuery.setQueryPart(sqmOriginalQuerySpec.copy(SqmCopyContext.simpleContext()));

Root<T> subQuerySelectRoot = (Root<T>) sqmSubQuery.getRoots().iterator().next();
sqmSubQuery.multiselect(subQuerySelectRoot.get("id").alias("id"));

countQuery.select(builder.count(builder.literal(1)));
countQuery.from(sqmSubQuery);
```

Comment: Where do the `Sqm...` classes come from?

Comment: These are the imports.


import org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.SqmCopyContext;
import org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.select.SqmQuerySpec;
import org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.select.SqmSelectStatement;
import org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.select.SqmSubQuery;

Comment: Ah, those are the hibernate specific implementations of the JPA API. The problem is that you cannot select from a subquery but only from an entity type. See [here](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/apidocs/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/criteria/abstractquery#from(jakarta.persistence.metamodel.EntityType))

Comment: How can I get the count query fromt the select query which I already have.

Comment: Please provide an example for the native sql query that you would like to write in hibernate. Currently you do not specify an entity (or table in native sql) in either the query or the subquery

Comment: Below is the expected native query to get generated.

select count(1) from (select distinct employee_type from Employee) a;

Also, there is a reference to the above code, https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15434

Answer (score 0):

Based on you comment you want to select the distinct count of all employee types. The query you provided should be equivalent to `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT employee_type) FROM Employee`.

This can be written in JPA as shown below:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Employee> employeeRoot = countQuery.from(Employee.class);
countQuery.select(builder.countDistinct(employeeRoot.get("type")));
Long count = entityManager.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();
```

where `type` is the name of the property that maps to the column `employee_type`

Comment: Well, this method is a reusable one and common for many CriteriaQueries, so we can't hardcode the particular entity class.

Answer (score 0):

The type `org.hibernate.query.criteria.JpaSelectCriteria` declares this method:

```
<X> JpaDerivedRoot<X> from(jakarta.persistence.criteria.Subquery<X> subquery);
```

which is the one you need to call if you're trying to use a subquery in the from clause.

And `SqmSelectStatement` implements `JpaSelectCriteria`. (It is also the object which implements `jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery`.)

So you can cast any `CriteriaQuery` to `JpaSelectCriteria` and call `from()`:

```
CriteriaQuery<Thing> query = ... ;
Subquery<OtherThing> subquery = ... ;
((JpaSelectCriteria<Thing>) query).from(subquery);
```

or whatever (I did not test this code).

Comment: Thanks Gavin, This worked, but getting the below error. 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Component at index 0 has no alias, but alias is required